# Controller calling the wrong RazorViewEngine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razorengine

The controller is going to the wrong ViewEngine. Here is the ViewEngines list

[image: ViewEngines]

The controller is from the `Lendlease.RET.Web.MVC` project but its rendering the `Lendlease.Com.Web.MVC` ViewEngine.

How can I force the controller to use the `Lendlease.RET.Web.MVC` RazorViewEngine?

I have `ReplaceEngine` code in `App_Start` folder

```
public static void ReplaceEngine<T>(this ViewEngineCollection engines, IViewEngine replacement)
            where T : IViewEngine
        {
            var engine = engines.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T));
            if (engine != null)
            {
                engines.Remove(engine);
            }
            engines.Add(replacement);
        }
```

Its replacing the ViewEngine correctly .When I debugged the code, it adds the `Lendlease.RET.Web.MVC` ViewEngine but the controller is going to the `Lendlease.Com.Web.MVC` ViewEngine.

How can I force the controller to use the RET RazorViewEngine?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your custom view engine at the Application_Start() event in Global.asax file.

```
 var myVeieWngine = new CustomViewEngine();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(myVeieWngine);
```

And here is the skeleton representation of CustomViewEngine

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{ }
```

Comment: its already registered in the App_Start . When I debugged the code, it goes to the App_Start code which is registering the ViewEngine but when I debugged the controller it goes to the wrong ViewEngine @Ashish

Comment: I tried clearing the ViewEngines but then it doesn't work for the other codebases